# Application is buffering and taking lot of time while watching videos - Performance issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, mongodb, codeigniter

I have developed application in PHP 7.2, apache2 with MongoDB database. i have deployed application code on 8GB RAM with 160GB hard disk, 8000 GB bandwidth on Ubuntu 18.04 O/S. Please let me know I can provide server side logs . THe no. of Application users are around 2000 users only, there is peak load during day time between 7:00 am to 4:00 pm local time. from past one week, this application is running very slow, I need experienced PHP developer can find the root cause of the performance problem... this is a online school app .. it contains list of videos that are stored on unix directory.. and other side of the appl students access the application using their login for respective class. students are accessing the application using their login but the problem is videos are buffering and taking lot of time while watching the videos

Comment: And the slowdown only happens at peak hours? Sounds like you don't have enough bandwidth.  You sure you have an 8 terrabyte connection?   Check your logs during that time to see how many videos are being accessed and you can figure out how much data is being pulled from the server at once.

Comment: Are you using simple video formats or more modern ones like HLS or MPEG-DASH? These formats are optimized for streaming and should reduce some of the load on the server by allowing each process to release quicker, and they also allow scrubbing to occur without needing to download the entire video, first. Also, what is your webserver? You might need to optimize the number of connections. Can you offload the videos to a third party like a CDN? They are relatively cheap, secure and literally built for this.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am using simple MP4 format of the videos. These videos are placed in unix directory and i am reading them from students login. I am using APACHE2 webserver. i have these parameters regarding the number of connections

Comment: <pre> root@jjronlinewebsites:/etc/apache2/mods-available# cat mpm_prefork.conf
  # MaxRequestWorkers: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxConnectionsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
StartServers       10
MinSpareServers    10
MaxSpareServers    20
        ServerLimit 800
        MaxRequestWorkers         800
        MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
</pre>

Comment: It looks like you're being limited by the server's network interface capacity. The 8000 GB bandwidth refers to the allowed transfer volume, not the throughput. 
You should offload the content delivery to a CDN